# Doubt in exponential distribution question.

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

The amount of time that a surveillance camera will run without having to be reset is a random variable having the exponential distribution with mean 50 days. My question is

if $X$ is amount of time

1. $P$(camera have to reset in less than 20 days) is it $P(X<20)$ or $1-P(X<20)$?
2. $P$(no have to reset in atleast 60 days), is it $P(X>60)$ or $P(X<60)$?

Comment: How would you describe the event $\{X<20\}$ in words?

Comment: maybe the cumulative distribution function has caused confusion here  P(x < 20) = 1- exp(-20 / 50)  in this case, that isn't the same as 1 - P(x < 20) though, it is P(X<20)

Comment: @drhab - I'm working on the theory that the format of the CDF is what is leading to the confusion, it happens to be in the format 1 - {expression}, but not for the reasons suggested in the question.  anyway, he's supposed to show us some workings, i though they were his workings.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$~$exp(\frac{1}{50})$ is the time when the camera needs a reset (the exponentially distributed time) then $P(X<t)$ will be the probability that it will need a reset before time $t$.

Answer (score 0):

"Amount of time that camera will run without having to be reset" = " camera will work from time $0$ to $<t$  and fail at time $t+dt$".
1 = failure within $20$ days = $P(X<20)$
2 = failure after $60$ days = $P(60 \leqslant X)=1-P(X<60)$